# shift position in matrix

Tags: matrix, netlogo

I have a `n x 1` matrix. I'm trying to find a way to "shift" all the elements position (loosing the last element) and then add an element in position 0,0 in this way:

From

```
[[ 10 ]
 [  5 ]
 [  2 ]
 [  3 ]
 [  1 ]
 [  5 ]]
```

to (adding a new element `2` in position 0,0)

```
[[ 2  ]
 [ 10 ]
 [  5 ]
 [  2 ]
 [  3 ]
 [  1 ]]
```

I'm pretty close to the solution but I don't know how add elements to a nested list.

```
;initial matrix
set mymatrix matrix:from-column-list [[10 5 2 3 1 5]]

;temp
let list matrix:to-column-list mymatrix


let tmplist matrix:to-column-list states

; ERROR here: the result of fput is [2[10 5 2 3 1 5]]
set tmplist fput 2 tmplist

;new matrix
matrix:set-column mymatrix 0 tmplist
```

**EDIT**: I realized that indeed for my needs a matrix is an overkill. I solved switching to pure netlogo lists and doing my business in map-reduce.

Comment: Can you explain why you are maintaining a matrix rather than a list?  What are your goals? It seems likely that you are turning a simple need for a data structure into needless code complexity.

Comment: After this operation I have to multiply this vector with another vector (`matrix:times-element-wise`), a matrix is convenient in this usage..

Comment: My question stands.  If you are repeatedly adjusting the data, then you should use a list for this book keeping.  You can still convert whenever you need.  But it does not sound like you need, if your multiplication is really just the elementwise multiplication you describe.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need elementwise multiplication of objects that are fundamentally one-dimensional, just use `map`.

Example: `(map * [1 2] [3 4])` reports `[3 8]`.

Now you can just do your bookkeeping with lists, which is much easier.

Even if (for some reason you have not stated) you really need matrix operations elsewhere, you almost surely should use lists for the bookkeeping you describe and then convert when necessary.